# A conjecture on partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic-combinatorics

**Conjecture:** Let $n$ $∈$ $N$. Then for each factor $m ≥ n$ of $n$($n + 1$)/$2$, one can partition the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots , n\}$ into disjoint subsets such that the sum of elements in each subset is equal to $m$.

The conjecture is based on numerical evidence.

Comment: This is an interesting question! You write 'prove that...' not 'is it true that...?' or 'prove or give a counterexample...'. What makes you so sure that it is true? Did you compute lots of examples?

Comment: Yeah i did compute some examples and i made this conjecture.

Comment: Anyone who can settle this ???

Comment: Nice question! When $n$ is even and $m=n+1$ you can take the sets $\{1, n\}, \{2, n-1\}, \ldots, \{n/2, n/2 + 1\}$.  This amounts to one of the proofs of the formula $\sum_{k=1}^n k = n(n+1)/2$.  But I'm guessing you know this already - perhaps this is was what motivated you to consider the question.

Comment: More generally, if $m = (n+1)k$ and $k | n$, then you can take the $n/k$ sets $\{1,n-1, 2, n-2, \ldots, k, n-k\}, \{k+1, n-k-1, k+2, n-k-2, \ldots, 2k, n-2k\}, \ldots$

Comment: I’ve edited the question to make it clear that this is a conjecture, in hopes of forestalling a fifth vote to close it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partition of ${1, 2, ... , n}$ into subsets with equal sums.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438911/partition-of-1-2-n-into-subsets-with-equal-sums)